# PHP - Twitter Developer - Getting number of tweets posted from a user

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I wanna get the numbers of tweet of a user_id.

I do this:

```
 $connection->get('users/show', array('user_id ' => $id));
```

but the response is:

```
stdClass Object
(
[errors] => Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => 34
            [message] => Sorry, that page does not exist.
        )

)

)
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Thank you too much Dumra. That was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Try 
`$connection->get('users/show', array('user_id' => $id));`

Just remove space in ur key 'user_id'

Comment: @durma "Try  $connection->get('users/show', array('user_id' => $id));" removing space in my key 'user_id' works. monster :)